# Average Mongodb with python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I've this json file with some 14 arrays each one with a number and I'm trying to get the average of all in MongoDB with python but I'm getting null in the answer.

```
{'_id': ObjectId('618af03902cd107477e3f2b9'), 
 "Time":[1364,1374,1384],
 "yaw":[0.15,0.3,0.45],
 "pitch":[0.36,0.76,1.08],
 "roll":[-0.13,-0.25,-0.35],
 "ax":[-0.42,-0.41,-0.41],
 "ay":[-0.15,-0.13,-0.1],
 "az":[0.9,0.91,1],
 "gx":[0,0,0],
 "gy":[-0.01,0,-0.01],
 "gz":[0.02,0.02,0.02],
 "mx":[0.26,0.26,0.26],
 "my":[0.01,0.01,0.01],
 "mz":[-0.04,-0.04,-0.07]
 }
```

I want to average time, yaw, pitch and I have this query in Python for MongoDB:

```py
@app.route('/sta')
def sta():
    docs = db.basetest.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": '618af03902cd107477e3f2b9', "avgTest" : {"$avg":"Time"}} }])
    for document in docs:
        return document
```

I'm getting this return:

```
{
    "_id": "618af03902cd107477e3f2b9",
    "avgTest": null
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you want to get the average of all values? Or the average from each one?

Comment: I want the average of each array separate, time: average of the 3 values , yaw: average of the 3 values and so on. In my code i'm only testing one parameter (time) to see if it works.

Comment: $avg can be used with arrays also you don't need the group [see this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2Xuo9dMfYB7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more dynamic solution would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         data: {
            $filter: {
               input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
               cond: { $ne: ["$$this.k", "_id"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { data: { $map: { input: "$data", in: { k: "$$this.k", v: { $avg: "$$this.v" } } } } } },
   { $replaceWith: { $mergeObjects: [{ _id: "$_id" }, { $arrayToObject: "$data" }] } }
])
```

If you want the average over **all** documents, then it becomes more complex. I found this solution, maybe there is a shorter/better one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $group: { _id: null, data: { $push: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } } },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$data",
               initialValue: [],
               in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $unwind: "$data" },
   { $group: { _id: "$data.k", v: { $push: "$data.v" } } },
   { $match: { _id: { $ne: "_id" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         v: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$v",
               initialValue: [],
               in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $set: { _id: "$$REMOVE", k: "$_id", v: { $avg: "$v" } } },
   { $group: { _id: null, data: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
   { $replaceWith: { $arrayToObject: "$data" } }
])
```

A different solution is this one, it may have better performance:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $unset: "_id" },
   { $group: { _id: null, data: { $push: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } } },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$data",
               initialValue: [],
               in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $map: {
               input: { $setUnion: "$data.k" },
               as: "k",
               in: { $filter: { input: "$data", cond: { $eq: ["$$this.k", "$$k"] } } }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $map: {
               input: "$data",
               as: "val",
               in: {
                  k: { $first: "$$val.k" },
                  v: {
                     $avg: {
                        $reduce: {
                           input: "$$val.v",
                           initialValue: [],
                           in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $replaceWith: { $arrayToObject: "$data" } }
])
```

Comment: This works to average for example 10 documents or only one document? Thanks a lot

Comment: Also for many documents (I skipped `{$match: {_id: ObjectId('618af03902cd107477e3f2b9')}}`). It calculates averages per document.

Comment: i Want to calculate the all average of 10 equal documents. Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "10 equal documents"?

Comment: 10 json documents like i post. Average for more than one document stored in mongodb. I'm making a database test and i need to compare the time between mongodb and mysql

Comment: Again, what do you mean by "10 documents"? Just the first 10 documents of a collection? If yes, what do you consider as "first"? Any condition or order?

Comment: I'm making tests for my project master. I need to take the times of average 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and 10 documents. Not each document average but all. The documents are like the json that i post. Sorry for my english

Comment: I give up! I asked already two times: What is document 1,2,3,4...?

Comment: just the numbers of documents, how many are store in mongodb. 10 documents in total

Comment: Then add `{$limit: 10}` but the result is not determined!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) operator in a `$project` stage (or `$set` or `$addFields` if you prefer) like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "Time": {"$avg": "$Time"},
      "yaw": {"$avg": "$yaw"},
      "pitch": {"$avg": "$pitch"},
      "roll": {"$avg": "$roll"},
      "ax": {"$avg": "$ax"},
      "ay": {"$avg": "$ay"},
      "az": {"$avg": "$az"},
      "gx": {"$avg": "$gx"},
      "gy": {"$avg": "$gy"},
      "gz": {"$avg": "$gz"},
      "mx": {"$avg": "$mx"},
      "my": {"$avg": "$my"},
      "mz": {"$avg": "$mz"}
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mOOV5r2K_M0)

Comment: thanks for the help, it solve my problem. just one more question, It's possible to get the average of 10 documents or only 1?

Comment: To get the value for more documents you need to use `$group` and later the `$project` stage. Also you can use `$limit` if you only want a predefined value of documents.

Comment: i put "$group" :{ "_id":"$_id", count : { project...} but it says unknown group operator '$project'

Comment: Try [this query](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GTbo4v-8BbT)